# Flutter: How to pass variables from StatelessWidget to StatefulWidget

Tags: android, dart, flutter

The problem is that I cannot pass the values of my own class ForceSelection values from another screen to another screen's StatefulWidget. It works fine in StatelessWidget. I have tried to learn from this flutter tutorial: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data#4-navigate-and-pass-data-to-the-detail-screen

I have this kind of class in levelSelection.dart

```
class ForceSelection {
  final String forceSelection;
  final String langSelection;

  ForceSelection(this.forceSelection, this.langSelection);
}
```

I am trying to pass the values to next file PlayQuiz.dart

```
Game(forceSelection: ForceSelection('maa', 'fin'))
```

game.dart looks like this:

```
class Game extends StatelessWidget {
  final ForceSelection forceSelection;

  Game({Key key, @required this.forceSelection}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: forceSelection.langSelection, // TODO should work and change later
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: PlayQuiz(),
    );
  }
}
```

And I want to pass the ForceSelection values to PlayQuiz()

```
class PlayQuizState extends State<PlayQuiz> {
  Game.forceSelection // <--- How can I get the value out of here?
}

class PlayQuiz extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PlayQuizState createState() => new PlayQuizState(); 
}
```

The whole code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/nKssz42R
and also levelSelection.dart: https://pastebin.com/8QbBD0A2

Comment: Do you wish to pass from parent -> child or child -> parent?

Comment: Did my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code

**Added forceSelecton argument in PlayQuiz()**

```
class Game extends StatelessWidget {
final ForceSelection forceSelection;

Game({Key key, @required this.forceSelection}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: forceSelection.langSelection, // TODO should work and change later
    theme: new ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    home: PlayQuiz(forceSelection),
  );
 }
}
```

**In Play Quiz**

```
class PlayQuiz extends StatefulWidget {
  final ForceSelection forceSelection;

  PlayQuiz(this.forceSelection);

  @override
  PlayQuizState createState() => new PlayQuizState(forceSelection); 
}
```

**In PlayQuizState**

```
class PlayQuizState extends State<PlayQuiz> {
  ForceSelection forceSelection;

  PlayQuizState(ForceSelection forceSelection) {
    this.forceSelection = forceSelection;
  }
}
```

Comment: don't pass objects as args. instead, use widget.forceSelection in the state class. It is the better approach. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget-in-flutter/50818870#50818870